# How to get Vertical Tabs at left of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I want to make Vertical scrollable tabs in android as in the pictures below.

[image: hello sms app]

this is when we swipe from left

[image: hello sms app]

or like this just static Tabs on the left side

[vertical tabs http://www.resco.net/mobileformstoolkit/images/wm/TabControl-02.png](http://www.resco.net/mobileformstoolkit/images/wm/TabControl-02.png)

this app have the exact implementation that i want. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hellotext.hello&hl=en.

I just wana ask the proper way to do it. Like every tab in the vertical scrollview on leftside have its own fragment on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

https://github.com/StevenRudenko/ActionsContentView/tree/master/ActionsContentViewLib

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

Look into this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html

Its exactly for this purpose.